# playing animation in the forground while the application is running in the background-IPHONE

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a client who says they want an messaging based app which has to do the following.

1) if the application goes to the background it should be polling the server to get the messages.

2)he also wants an animation to be played(series of images) when a message comes and any message gets deleted form the database in the background. (for example -- let say i quit my messaging app and it goes to the background,now i opened a calculator app and i am doing some calculations, now if a message comes in, i should be alerted by a visual images palyed in series on the calculator app (in other words i want to say - regardless of any other app i am running).

I think i can accomplish the first one but i am not sure about the second point. can any one tell me how the second issue can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the first one by using Push Notifications. The second one you cannot do directly except for maybe with a jail broken device. However, what you could do, is have a standard push notification message come up telling the user they received the message and when they select "view" it will open your app where you could play the animation. I believe you can show an image with a push notification but not an animation.

Answer (score 0):

The two things your client wants:

1. Not unless your app pretends to be a VoIP or GPS app; and Apple will reject any app that doesn't function as intended.
2. No. At most you can fire a Local Notification from the background (but only if you meet the above).

Answer (score 0):

Think your stuck with the boring old apple notifications.